# Android/Java Implements Runnable enters an infinite loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

I am connecting two Android Devices P2P using the following code.  The problem is that when the server receives data from client its Thread/Runnable doesn't stop.

Please suggest me a way to stop/forced this to go in an infinite loop.

Following Is the piece of code I am using for my Server Activity :

```
       public class ServerThread implements Runnable {
            private volatile boolean keepGoing = true;

               public void requestStop() {
                   keepGoing = false;
                }
               public void run() {
                   try {
                       if (SERVERIP != null) {
                           handler.post(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                      serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (true) {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new            
                             InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        line = null;
                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    serverStatus.setText(line);


                                    Log.d("IP recevied", line);
                                    requestStop();
                                    //finish();

                                    //Intent i = new Intent(ServerActivity.this, 
                                        //ClientActivity.class);
                                    //startActivity(i);
                                    //serverStatus.setText(line);
                                    // do whatever you want to the front end
                                    // this is where you can be creative
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. 
                                        Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
                       }
                              } catch (Exception e) {
                                  handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                     @Override
                           public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error");
                           }
                       });
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }
```

EDIT:

```
   while (keepGoing) {
         // listen for incoming clients
         Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
         handler.post(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
             }
         });

         try {
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new            
                  InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
             line = null;
             while (((line = in.readLine()) != null) && keepGoing) {
                 Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                 handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {

                         serverStatus.setText(line);


                         Log.d("IP recevied", line);
                         requestStop();
                         //finish();

                         //Intent i = new Intent(ServerActivity.this, 
                             //ClientActivity.class);
                         //startActivity(i);
                         //serverStatus.setText(line);
                         // do whatever you want to the front end
                         // this is where you can be creative
                     }
                 });
             }
```

Comment: Change `while (true)` to `while (keepGoing)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that even though you signal the server to stop, it's still stuck in the call to `serverSocket.accept();`, waiting for other clients to connect. What you should do is also close the socket in the stop method:

```
public void requestStop() {
      keepGoing = false;
      serverSocket.close();
}
```

to force the code to throw an `IOException` and then recheck the `while` condition and exit.

Comment: wouldn't this also close the socket for further communication with the connected server/client?

Comment: @user387184: The server socket doesn't communicate anything. It just accepts client connections and creates corresponding local socket objects (the results of accept). Sure, you won't be able to reuse it later, but then that's the point of stopping the server no?

Comment: That's interesting, since with BT sockets it is different - there I have used the socket to connect as well as get the input and outut streams for data communication - thanks very much for clarifying!

Comment: +1 to put up a very long and only semi-coherent question dude.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you comment the line

```
  //finish();
```

once the connection is established?

Since you never finish once you are connected you have an infinite loop

Comment: it didn't make any difference. if i finish the activity thread still runs......and displayed in logcat

Comment: add the line: keepGoing = false before finish and change as hmjd suggested. Does it show "IP recevied" ?

Comment: you have the two loops - so you keep on receiving data! make sure either no data is sent after the IP OR take the second  while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)  out and start another piece of code that communicates outside this connection routine!

Comment: Still having same issue, I think i didn't get your Point can you Please Modify the Code. Thanks

Comment: Please see my edit above... BUT you need to start managing the data exchange in another routine then!